# Libcurl request no result

Tags: c++, curl, elasticsearch, libcurl

I use the libcurl extension in C++. I send a request to a elasticsearch server but the result is ´null`.
I have rebuild the curl request in PHP and it worked.
How can i get the result from the webserver?

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;

std::stringstream ss_url; 
ss_url << "http://IP/newgame/player/2/_update";

char *post_url = const_cast<char*>(ss_url.str().c_str());


curl = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, post_url);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 9200);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{ "doc": { "x": 555555, "y": 287273 }}');
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

EDIT:

I have tried to log the curl answer. But the file is empty.

```
FILE *curllog = fopen("/home/elasticsearch_curl.log", "w+");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, curllog);
```

Comment: Check the headers of what the server returns and you probably will figure it out. It could very well be a redirect for example and your code doesn't ask libcurl to follow such...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if there is a problem with post_url cast by replacing it with the actual string. in curl_set_opt of CURLOPT_URL

`curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com");`

It may be the problem. It's working for me.
include this after curl_easy_perform for debug and check.

`if(res != CURLE_OK) {
 fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform()failed:%s\n",curl_easy_strerror(res));}`

A Working GET EXAMPLE:
https://gist.github.com/k3ut0i/737b6d19713ef5aa0a74

Comment: Thanks for help! I have already try to replace post_url with the actual string. If i print `res` i get `null` if i print `curl_easy_strerror(res)` i get `no error`. But it seems if the request will not send. Do you have an idea how i can test if the request go out? Like with a "Test URL" or so.

Comment: @Tobias did you check if GET version of your script is working? print res will not work. check my edited answer to print resonse string